# Can't import my own file python, Flask pycharm

Tags: python, flask, import, pycharm

#### Image of project structure:

[image: image of project structure]

I have got this kind of files. I want to import `write_block` function from `block.py` in `main.py` through `from block import *`.

It says name error and `write_block` is not defined.

Comment: Zipper, you will need an `__init__.py` in every directory you want to import a file from - whether a relative or absolute import. The presence of that file, which may be empty, indicates that directory is a python package and has code one may import.

Answer (score 0):

Try a relative import.

`from .block import *`

By the way you should try to avoid * imports.

If you want learn more about imports just take a look at [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)